# Why is Spring Ingoring a Eclipse Linked Source Package?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a small Spring Boot application for a relative one using a microservice architecture. As multiple service will be sharing some code I created a project named domain to stored all shared classes. I created another project, called configuration, for retrieving parameters from the database. While trying to inject a Repository in a RestController, Spring console is telling it can't find the repository to inject. So far, I've tried to link the source project and add as a module dependency in eclipse. I also added the packages scan in the Application class, but without sucess. On the other hand, external classes are compiling sucessfully. The issue seems to be on Spring Dependecy Injection while importing external eclipse project.

**Repository**

```
@Service
public interface ComponentRepository extends JpaRepository<Component, Integer> {

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
```

public class ConfigurationController {

```
@Autowired
private ComponentRepository repository;

@GetMapping(path = "/configuration/{component}")
public Optional<Component> getConfiguration(@PathVariable Component component) {
    
    return repository.findById(3);//fixed whitle troubleshooting.
    
}

}
```

**Application Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "ofi.marina.configuration", "ofi.marina.domain" })
public class ConfigurationApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigurationApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

**Linked Source and Exclusions**
[image: link source]

[image]

**Error Running From Maven**

```
2022-03-06 15:52:03.219  INFO 7196 --- [           main] o.m.c.ConfigurationApplication           : Starting ConfigurationApplication using Java 17.0.1 on XXXX with PID 7196 (E:\JhonnyOnedrive\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\MarinaOFI\Source\configuration\target\classes started by XXXXX in E:\JhonnyOnedrive\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\MarinaOFI\Source\configuration)
2022-03-06 15:52:03.222  INFO 7196 --- [           main] o.m.c.ConfigurationApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-06 15:52:03.853  INFO 7196 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-06 15:52:03.907 ERROR 7196 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type ofi.marina.domain.Component not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1211) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:502) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.buildTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:271) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:248) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.getTypeVariableMap(ClassTypeInformation.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.getTypeVariableMap(ClassTypeInformation.java:104) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<init>(ClassTypeInformation.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(ClassTypeInformation.java:71) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.<init>(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.DefaultRepositoryMetadata.<init>(DefaultRepositoryMetadata.java:49) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.getMetadata(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at ofi.marina.configuration.ConfigurationApplication.main(ConfigurationApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ofi.marina.domain.Component
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.715 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-06T15:52:03-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default-cli) on project configuration: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default-cli) on project configuration: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm(RunMojo.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm(AbstractRunMojo.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Error Running From Eclipse**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ofi.marina.configuration.ConfigurationApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ofi.marina.configuration.ConfigurationApplication
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it working. As this is a pet project today i continue tinkering with it. So far 3 changes made it:

1. Added @ComponentScan to scan the other package

**Application Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"ofi.marina.domain"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ofi.marina.domain"})
public class ParametersApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ParametersApplication.class, args);
        
    }

}
```

2. Change the repository from @Service to @Component

   @Component
   public interface ComponentRepository extends JpaRepository<ConfigurationComponent, Integer> {

   ```
   }
   ```
3. Removed a class from linked source that was not meant to be included(Is possible that this alone fixed it IDK. Need more tests).

Now Im reorganizing the workspace to avoid this bad designs mistakes. But I hope anybody struggling with a situation like this can find this post.

Answer (score 1):

Your packages do not match. The class ofi.marina.domain.Component has this package:
ofi.marina.domain

But your Spring Boot main class ConfigurationApplication has a different package o.m.c.
I guess o.m.c.ConfigurationApplication might be ofi.marina.cXYZ.ConfigurationApplication. So you have to change your Component class package to ofi.marina.cXYZ.Component. Or use Spring @Import to load classes in different root packages.

Comment: For this context, application is Configuration and imported project is Domain. I recognize the difference in packages name and it is like that because I wanted the source in domain to be shared in configuration. The only thing not working is injecting dependencies, but it compiles and start if I remove the @autowired annotations.

Comment: But then Spring's automatic search for beans does not work, that is why you have this error. You can shift ConfigurationApplication one package folder up to be:
ofi.marina.ConfigurationApplication
Or you think about another package structure.

Comment: This sound good. I’ll try this one and let you know.